# Swift: Trying to print "Double Sided" UIPrintInfo.Duplex.longEdge but not working

Tags: ios, swift, printing, uiprintinteractioncntrler, uiprintinfo

I am trying to print PDF double side in iOS app, for that setting         printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfo.Duplex.longEdge, but it is ignored when I print using UIPrintInteractionController

```
    printInfo.printerID = "c890E8700000.local"
    printInfo.jobName = lastPathComponent
    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfo.Duplex.longEdge
    printInfo.orientation = UIPrintInfo.Orientation.portrait
    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
    
    
    print(printInfo.dictionaryRepresentation)


    // this is what I see in debug print
    Optional([
      AnyHashable("UIPrintInfoPrinterIDKey"): c890E8700000.local,
      AnyHashable("UIPrintInfoJobNameKey"): 02180830225_bg.pdf
    ])
```